# ReactJS get external Json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a component with Reactjs to get json from an url, I tried with (Axios, Fetch, Jsonp...) and other package.
With Axios and Jsonp I had CORS errors, impossible to fix the issue.
With Fetch I can disable the cors with `'mode': 'no-cors'` but no data are collected.

Here is my code :

```
getData() {

    const header = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'mode': 'no-cors'
    };

    this.serverRequest = fetch('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Exchange/GetTradePairChart?tradePairId=5355&dataRange=2&dataGroup=60', header)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
            this.setState({
                altcoinsData: json
            });
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
}
```

Error :

**SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at App.js:30
    at**

Comment: If the other server doesn't support CORS or JSONP, you won't be able to fetch it from the client. Learn about the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: There is no way to get this json ?

Comment: You can write a proxy on a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are  using webpack-dev-server, add proxy service in webpack.config.js to avoid CROS.

```
devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        stats: 'errors-only',
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:20404', //http://localhost:20403/',
                secure: false
            }
        }
}
```

If not you can start a express server with http-proxy-middleware to proxy the ajax request to the required end point. Please find a sample server.js which includes express and webpack config.

Hope it helps :)

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var Agent = require('agentkeepalive');
var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
var https = require('https');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const express = require('express');
const path = require("path");
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');

var app = express();
var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(
    '/api',
    proxy({
        target: 'http://10.134.116.186:1521/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        agent: new Agent({
            maxSockets: 100,
            keepAlive: true,
            maxFreeSockets: 10,
            keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
            timeout: 6000000,
            keepAliveTimeout: 90000 // free socket keepalive for 90 seconds
        })
    })
);
app.use(
    '/dist',
    proxy({
        target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        agent: new Agent({
            maxSockets: 100,
            keepAlive: true,
            maxFreeSockets: 10,
            keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
            timeout: 6000000,
            keepAliveTimeout: 90000 // free socket keepalive for 90 seconds
        })
    })
);
app.use(
    webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: config.output.path,
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath,  
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
    })
);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(7071, 'localhost', function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Webpack Dev Server is fired up!!');
});
```